# Разница во времени

Tags: sql, mysql

Есть быстрый способ получить разницу между datetime в днях:часах:минутах:секундах без написания трёхэтажных запросов? Я пока нашёл только `SELECT TIMEDIFF(s.hit_time, s.click_time) passed_time FROM table`, но к сожалению без дней. Как ни крути, а с днями получаются длинные запросы...

P.S.: Задача всё ещё актуальна, поэтому немного раскрою суть. В настоящий момент задача решена следующим образом:

```
select 
@t:=timediff('2013-04-02 23:30:18', '2013-02-20 10:12:00') diff,
CONCAT(
        if(extract(hour from @t)>24,round(extract(hour from @t)/24),0), ":",
        extract(hour from @t)%24, ":",
        TIME_FORMAT(@t, "%i:%s")
) passed_time;
```

В итоге `passed_time=35:22:59:59`. В принципе отформатировано всё так как мне нужно, вот только баг: `passed_time` всегда будет равен этому значению при подсчёте дат, различающихся более чем на 35 дней. Как мне получить правильное значение в нужном формате? Если считаете что задача тривиальна, то попробуйте сделать сами. Буду благодарен за ответ, так как я уже зашёл в тупик.

Answer (score 1):

А DATEDIFF Вам чем не нравится?

Comment: Возвращает количество дней. В частности `SELECT concat(DATEDIFF(hit_time, click_time), ':', TIMEDIFF(hit_time, click_time)) passed_time FROM table` может вернуть "41:838:59:59"

Answer (score 0):

А если так:

```
set @d1 = '2013-04-02 23:30:18';
set @d2 = '2013-02-20 10:12:00';

select concat(
    datediff(@d1, @d2), ':', time_format( from_unixtime((unix_timestamp(@d1) - unix_timestamp(@d2)) - datediff(@d1, @d2)*86400), '%H:%I:%S' )
);
```